# Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod]

Tags: angularjs

i am using below code. But i am getting error Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod]. The module name is same. Not sure why i am getting this error. Please help. i checked the syntax, names etc everywhere but could not find any issues. it seems like i missed something simple but not able to figure out where exactly i made a mistake.

```js
   angular.module("demo").controller("SimpleDemoController", function($scope) {

    $scope.models = {
     selected: null,
     lists: {"A": [], "B": []}
    };

    // Generate initial model
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
     $scope.models.lists.A.push({label: "Item A" + i});
     $scope.models.lists.B.push({label: "Item B" + i});
    }

    // Model to JSON for demo purpose
    $scope.$watch('models', function(model) {
     $scope.modelAsJson = angular.toJson(model, true);
    }, true);

   });
```

```css
   /**
    * The dnd-list should always have a min-height,
    * otherwise you can't drop to it once it's empty
    */
   .simpleDemo ul[dnd-list] {
    min-height: 42px;
    padding-left: 0px;
   }

   /**
    * The dndDraggingSource class will be applied to
    * the source element of a drag operation. It makes
    * sense to hide it to give the user the feeling
    * that he's actually moving it.
    */
   .simpleDemo ul[dnd-list] .dndDraggingSource {
    display: none;
   }

   /**
    * An element with .dndPlaceholder class will be
    * added to the dnd-list while the user is dragging
    * over it.
    */
   .simpleDemo ul[dnd-list] .dndPlaceholder {
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: block;
    min-height: 42px;
   }

   .simpleDemo ul[dnd-list] li {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
   }

   /**
    * Show selected elements in green
    */
   .simpleDemo ul[dnd-list] li.selected {
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    color: #3c763d;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./angular-drag-and-drop-lists.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body ng-app="demo">
  <!-- The dnd-list directive allows to drop elements into it. The dropped data will be added to the referenced list -->
  <ul dnd-list="list">
   <!-- The dnd-draggable directive makes an element draggable and will transfer the object that was assigned to it. If an element was dragged away, you have to remove it from the original list yourself using the dnd-moved attribute -->
   <li ng-repeat="item in list"
    dnd-draggable="item"
    dnd-moved="list.splice($index, 1)"
    dnd-effect-allowed="move"
    dnd-selected="models.selected = item"
    ng-class="{'selected': models.selected === item}">
    {{item.label}}
   </li>
  </ul> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When debugging, don't use the minified version of angular. If you use the non-minified, it will usually give a more descriptive error

Comment: Thanks for the tip. will follow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your module should have an empty dependencies injected

```
angular.module("demo",[]).controller("SimpleDemoController", function($scope) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: This has resolved the error. However the code inside function($scope) is not being called.if you know why, can you please let me know. am i doing anything wrong inside the function?

Comment: you need to add ng-controller. <body ng-app="demo" ng-controller="SimpleDemoController">